# How to Conditionally run the Scheduled job in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, conditional-statements, scheduled-tasks

I have scheduled job which runs incessantly after certain amount of time.

Now I want to run this scheduled job only if a condition is met. The condition is obtained at run time and it is not dependent on any configuration parameter.

How do I achieve this. I know Spring Boot 4.x provides this interface called Condition. But somehow my code doesnt work.

Here, is my code...

## ScheduledTask

```
@Configuration
public class ScheduleTask {
  @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "5000")
  @Conditional(SchedulerCondition.class)
  public void pollDepots() {
      System.out.println("Running");
  }
}
```

## Conditional Class

```
public class SchedulerCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        return false;   
//Here some condition needs to be implemented which is not dependent on the parameters of this method.
    }
}
```

Await your response.
Have a lovely day.

Answer (score 0):

You could pull your scheduled task in a different class:

```
public class ScheduledPollDepots {

    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "1000")
    public void pollDepots() {
        System.out.println("Running");
    }
}
```

Then create a bean based on the conditional:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    @Conditional(SchedulerCondition.class)
    public ScheduledPollDepots pollDepots() {
        return new ScheduledPollDepots();
    }

}
```

With your schedule condition as is:

```
public class SchedulerCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

it should work properly.